# RxSwift replay the last value of a completed observable

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a cold observable that may get called multiple times. This observable does an expensive task (a network request) and then completes. I would like this observable to only ever make a single network call and if I need to call it again in the future I would like to get the last emitted value.

If an observable doesn't complete (i.e. just sends a next value without a completed event) I can use the **.share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)** function to always get the last value. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with observables that completes at the end of the request. Bellow is an example:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let refreshSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let observable = Observable<String>.create { observer in
        let seconds = 2.0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
            observer.onNext("Hello, World")
            observer.onCompleted() // <-- Works when commented out
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    }
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)

    refreshSubject
        .flatMap { _ in observable }
        .subscribe(onNext: { response in
            print("response: ", response)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

@IBAction func refreshButtonHandler(_ sender: Any) {
    refreshSubject.onNext(())
}
```

Every time the **refreshSubject** is triggered it takes 2 seconds for the **Hello, World** to be printed. If I remove the **observer.onCompleted()** line however, it only takes 2 seconds the first time and subsequently returns a cached response.

Obviously this is just an example, in the real world I would not have any control if the observable completes or not but I would like to always just replay the last value regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't want the cold observable to be re-subscribed to even when the refresh is triggered. In that case, this is the solution:

```swift
Observable.combineLatest(refreshSubject.startWith(()), yourColdObservable)
    .map { $0.1 }
    .subscribe(onNext: { val in
        print("*** val: ", val)
    })
```

Using `flatMap` means that the observable is re-subscribed to every time an event enters the flatMap. By using combineLatest instead, the cold observable will only be subscribed to once. The combineLatest operator will store the result of the observable internally and emit it again every time the refresh subject emits.
(No `share` is needed for this method.)

Answer (score 1):

```swift
let yourColdObservable = Observable<String>.create { observer in
    let seconds = 2.0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        observer.onNext("Hello, World")
        observer.onCompleted()
    }
    return Disposables.create()
}

let cacheObservable = refreshButton.rx.tap
    .startWith(())
    .flatMapLatest { _ in yourColdObservable }
    .share(replay: 1)

makeRequestWithCacheButton.rx.tap
    .flatMapLatest { _ in cacheObservable }
    .subscribe(onNext: { response in
        print("response: ", response)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**[StartWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)**

> emit a specified sequence of items before beginning to emit the items
>   from the source Observable
>   Such a fake tap on the refreshButton when starting the sequence

**[FlatMapLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)**

> The FlatMap operator transforms an Observable by applying a function
>   that you specify to each item emitted by the source Observable, where
>   that function returns an Observable that itself emits items. FlatMap
>   then merges the emissions of these resulting Observables, emitting
>   these merged results as its own sequence.
>   FlatMapLatest is special type of FlatMap, because it cancels previous Observable when `refreshButton.rx.tap` emit onNext event.

Comment: As a reminder, while it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s more useful if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: The insight here is that the `.share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)` has been attached to the flatMap's observable rather than the inner `observable`. The latter stays alive longer than the former.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not fully understanding this answer. I do understand what flatMapLatest does and the share() but I can't see how this will help me? In my understanding, the share() is able to 'cache' the observable only if it hasn't completed. Since my cold observable always completes, share() has no effect. Perhaps you could modify my code with you example in case I'm missing something (I wasn't able to adapt your code in way this would work)?

Comment: @nonstopcoding If the sequence is completed then `.share (replay: 1)` behaves like `Observable.just (...)`

Comment: Hi @AdrianBobrowski your code doesn't seem to solve the problem. Every time the refreshSubject fires an event (refreshButton.rx.tap in you scenario) it still takes 2 seconds to see the 'Hello, World' message to appear in console. The desired outcome is that it only takes 2 seconds the first time (as this simulates an expensive network call) but for subsequent calls the last value is reused (hence it should return instantly). Imagine that instead of my dummy observable that sends 'Hello, World' this was a call to 'URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: URLRequest(url: url))'  where url is an image.

Comment: @nonstopcoding when you tap on `refreshButton` then you will wait 2 seconds, but when you tap on `makeRequestWithCacheButton` then you wait only with 1st tap